Cadence Xcelium - Finding first signal to transition to X (don't care)
I have a gate level sdf annotated simulation that is not functioning as expected. After a certain timestamp, I see signals start going XXXX. According to the timing reports, there are no setup/hold violations, and I have even tried lowering the frequency to see if I got the same behavior as in my RTL simulations but so far, no luck.
I would like to use a TCL script to investigate what is the first signal that transitions to don't care. But I believe my docs are not update to date with my Xcelium version because I keep running into BADOPT error messages and I cannot find the good options for my script to run as intended.
set signals [scope -disciplines -recurse]

# Initialize variables to track the first 'X' transition
set first_x_signal ""
set first_x_time 1000000000000  ;# A large number to ensure any timestamp will be smaller

# Iterate through each signal
foreach signal $signals {
    # Get the waveform of the signal
    set waveform [xmsim get -waveform $signal]
    
    # Check the waveform for 'X' transitions
    set transitions [xmsim get -transitions $waveform]
    foreach transition $transitions {
        set value [xmsim get -value $transition]
        set time [xmsim get -time $transition]
        
        # Check if the value is 'X' and if it is the earliest 'X' transition
        if {$value == "X" && $time < $first_x_time} {
            set first_x_signal $signal
            set first_x_time $time
        }
    }
}

# Output the first signal to transition to 'X' and the timestamp
if {$first_x_signal != ""} {
    puts "The first signal to transition to 'X' is $first_x_signal at time $first_x_time"
} else {
    puts "No signal transitions to 'X' in the simulation."
}

